How to change the distinguishedName attribute for computer object in AD
How can I change the distinguishedName attribute of a computer object in ad using powershell. I used the following command:
Set-ADComputer -Identity WIN10 -Replace@{"distinguishedName"="CN=win10,OU=AADDC Computers,DC=gowilsonsgroup,DC=com"}  

but got an error as the assignment expression is not valid.

You can't update the distinguished name in this way.
Without further details, it's impossible for us to know why you are wanting to do this.
Looking at your command, it would seem that the CN or name is not changing, so we could guess that you are just trying to move the OU where the computer resides in AD:
 Move-ADObject -Identity (Get-ADComputer 'WIN10') -TargetPath 'OU=AADDC Computers,DC=gowilsonsgroup,DC=com'

Note that you will need to have the necessary rights to do this in the directory.
